# Crystal Reports selecting data from two different databases

Tags: crystal-reports, multiple-databases

I have a two databases that contain the exact same tables and are on the same server. I want to be able to create a report that will allow me to "merge" these databases so that when a user queries they will query BOTH databases at the same time. Is that even possible?

Comment: Do you want the values side-by-side (meaning linked on the common field) or combined (UNION one set with another)?

Comment: I think I'm looking for combined. Say I have a persons order Id. I'm not sure which database it's in. I would like to just query both databases at the same time as if it's one database and then find all the info linked to that order id. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to create database views that UNION ALL the values from the same tables in both databases - something like:

```
CREATE VIEW CombinedSalesTable AS
SELECT * FROM database1.SalesTable
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM database2.SalesTable
```

- and design the reports to query the views.

You may want to add an additional column to the views to show which database each record comes from, as a key value that is unique in one table may have a "duplicate" in the equivalent table in the other database.

Comment: Turns out I didn't need the "Create view line". It worked just with the union. Thanks!